# Upgrade Debian Jessie (8) to Buster (10) possible or need to go sequential in versions upgrades?

Tags: debian, upgrade

Just started working with a Debian Jessie (8) in a production environnent. While presently deployed it is not seeing any heavy use yet. I was looking at the OS [LTS page](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS), and I was thinking about how convenient it would be to just upgrade it before is start seeing some more steady use in our environment and possibly making things more complicated with a later upgrade.

I was looking for a procedure to upgrade from Debian v.8 to v.10 but most documented [procedures](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/) are sequential in order (e.g. 8 -> 9, or 9 -> 10).

My question: should I upgrade sequentially, or there is some proper documented way to skip a main version while upgrading?

Comment: Yes, you must upgrade it sequentially. It is not recommended to upgrade more than one release in one time.

Comment: You can upgrade there is no technical limitations (but exceptions) but if you're not a high grade technician you will just fail. Update one version at a time.

Comment: @francoisP there can be technical limitations, in some configurations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only supported upgrade path is to upgrade one release at a time, *i.e.* Debian 8 to 9, then 9 to 10. Each release has its own [release](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/index.en.html) [notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/index.en.html), with caveats which may or may not apply to you; it’s usually harder to deal with them all in one go over multiple releases...

There’s some amount of [skip testing](https://piuparts.debian.org/sid/source/m/mingw-w64.html) which goes on during a release’s development, but you’ll see there that there’s no automated `jessie22buster` suite. Package maintainers also try to preserve upgrade capabilities across two releases, but that’s a nice-to-have, not a requirement (for example, transitional packages are usually published in two releases, and conflicts are usually documented for at least two releases).

Of course, it could work; the major obstacle when upgrading is the adequacy of the old kernel, and the latest Debian 8 kernel is sufficient to deal with Debian 10. But I wouldn’t risk it, especially not on a production server. You’ll end up spending more time thinking about and researching the viability of skipping a release, than it would have taken to perform both upgrades back-to-back...

Comment: Yes I understand and this make sense, especially in a production environment where 'hacking around' is definitely not an option.